# CSS: Absolute positioned div extending beyond overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, overflow

I have a jquery product slider that rotates through several LI's that are floated left.  They have a width of 150px and height of 200px and have an image and a few bits of text in them.  The outer container div that holds the UL has an overflow:hidden so that only 5 LI's are displayed at a time.

This works great, until I try and stick an additional image in there with an absolute position bumped a few pixels above and to the left of the containing LI.

The goal is to have a transparent "sold" corner banner png image on the top left corner of the item, and it has a shadow and highlight that makes it look like it's bending around the sides of the LI.

It looks great, except the overflow:hidden seems to be cutting off those few extra pixels I have bumped it out.  I even tried adding extra margin and padding around the LI but it still gets cut off somehow.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="shadowblock_out">
<div class="shadowblockdir">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <div class="sliderblockdir">
        <div id="list">
            <div class="slider">
                <ul>
                    <li><div class="sold_90"><img src="sold_90.png" /></div>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="851441-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$50</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="827361-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$25</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="837216-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$55</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="940651-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$75</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="848712-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$90</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="903776-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$10</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>

                    <li>    
                    <div class="featured-image"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="125" src="278773-150x125.png" /></a></div>
                    <div class="featured-info">Product info here</div>
                    <span class="left">$100</span> 
                    <span class="right">XYZ</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /slider -->
        </div><!-- /list -->

        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div><!-- /sliderblock --> 
</div><!-- /shadowblock -->
```

And the css:

```
   .sold_90 {
        display:block;
        width:90px;
        height:90px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:9;
        left: -5px;
        top: -5px;
        overflow: visible;
    }


         .shadowblock_out { margin:0 0 20px 0; border:1px solid #F5CF5B; /* overflow:hidden; */}

        .shadowblockdir {
            height:245px;
            padding:8px 5px 5px;
            background:#FFFFFD;
            border:1px solid #fff;
        }
        /* featured listings homepage carousel */
        .featured-listings-home-top {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #8E633E;
            border-bottom-width: 1px;
            border-bottom-style: dotted;
            border-bottom-color: #A48061;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #8E633E;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .featured-listings-home-top span {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #8E633E;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        .sliderblockdir {
            height: 215px;
            padding-top: 5px;
        }

        .slider {
            float:left;
            left:-5000px;
            margin-left:15px;
            position:relative;  /* visibility:hidden; */
            height: 215px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .slider ul {
            width:600px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .slider ul li a {text-decoration:none; font-size: 12px; font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; line-height: 12px;  margin-top: 5px;}
        .slider ul li a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
        .slider ul li:hover {   background-color:#FDE051;}
        .slider ul li img { 

        }
        span.price_sm { font-size:11px;  font-style:italic;  color:#666}
        span.feat_left { float:left; text-align:center; width:55px; }
        #list {
            width:925px;
            margin:0 auto;
            height: 215px;
        }
        .slider {
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            left: 5px;
            width: 925px;
        }
        .slider ul {
            height:210px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .slider ul li {
            width:160px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #FFFFFD;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
            -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            overflow: visible;
        }
        .slider ul li a {text-decoration:none; font-size: 12px; font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; line-height: 12px;  margin-top: 5px;}
        .slider ul li a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
        .slider ul li:hover {   background-color:#FDE051;}
        .slider ul li img {
            cursor:pointer;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }
        span.price_sm { font-size:11px;  font-style:italic;  color:#666}
        span.feat_left { float:left; text-align:center; width:55px; }
        #list li p {
            display:block;
            white-space: pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
            white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
            text-align: center;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .captify { border:1px solid #CCC;  float:left;  margin:3px 10px 5px 0;  padding:2px;}
        .prev { cursor:pointer;  float:left;  padding-top:25px}
        .next { cursor:pointer;  float:right;  padding-top:25px}
        .featured_price {float:left; font-size: 10px; color:#FF0000; display: inline; width: 55px;}
        .featured_location {font-size: 10px; color:#000; float: right;display: inline;}
        .left {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            color: #AD6441;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
            width: 50px;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }

        .featured-image img {   
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #b7b7b7;
            -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

        }
        .featured-image {
            height: 125px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        .featured-info {
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #3F2A19;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            line-height: 14px;
        }
```

And here is the link to the "sold" image: http://bit.ly/h5Uozo ...

I didn't write this code, only am modifying it, but it's been giving me FITS trying to figure out how to get the little Sold image to extend beyond the LI box -3px so that it looks like it's "wrapping" around the box.  So if someone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I dont see the styles for `div.sold` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo on my end.  The div.sold should have actually said .sold_90 (like the image), and I forgot to include the class for that in my css snippet.  Sheesh sorry.  But they were there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/EGsad/

I added the following CSS:

```
.sold {
    z-index: 999;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: I made a typo in my original question, and the sold css was not included in my description, but it was in the code.  I've modified the original code in the question to be what is in my files. Sorry!!

Comment: I think it has something to do with something else in the rest of the page.  When I set up a test html page and view it locally, it works.  When I add it to the rest of the site, it breaks.  Maybe it's in the jQuery javascript somewhere.

Comment: @RodeoRamsey Can you please add the JS to the above question and I'll see if I can help further?

Comment: thank you, let me see if I can replicate it with as little extra added as possible.  I'll post back here soon.