# Ajax overlay div extends beyond parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The site I'm working on contains multiple panels on a page and within the body of each panel, the data is sorted by clicking on the column header. Each panel has its own div overlay that displays while the ajax request is sent. An example of a rendered page can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/rorourke/phnwqs0w/ This example has one of the overlays turned on (`display: block;`) as done so by the ajax script code. When the overlay is displayed by the ajax call, it extends beyond the confines of the parent div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" id="main">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="navbar navbar-light-page navbar-light-text">
            <div>
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-header-spacer">
                     <h2>Accounts w/ Active Units</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid container-border col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-collapsible panel-section" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse17"> Vectra 123

                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse17" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                    <div class="center-block" id="divLoading17" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: orange; font-size: larger; display: block; position: absolute; opacity: 0.4; background-color: dimgray; box-sizing: border-box;">Loading ....</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form4" action="/Report/Data/17" method="post" data-ajax-update="#balanceResults17" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-loading="#divLoading17" data-ajax="true">
                            <div id="balanceResults17">
                                <table class="table table-condensed">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="info">
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="Name">Unit Id</button>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="CommNumber">Comm #</button>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="AccountName">Account</button>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="ChargeNumber">Charge #</button>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>IASpro1
                                            </td>
                                            <td>103069</td>
                                            <td>Overhead
                                            </td>
                                            <td>ABC130257109</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>IASproX
                                            </td>
                                            <td>100154</td>
                                            <td>Overhead
                                            </td>
                                            <td>ABC130257109</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-collapsible panel-section" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse5"> Vectra 456

                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse5">
                    <div class="center-block" id="divLoading5" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: orange; font-size: larger; display: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0.4; background-color: dimgray;">Loading ....</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form5" action="/Report/Data/5" method="post" data-ajax-update="#balanceResults5" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-loading="#divLoading5" data-ajax="true">
                            <div id="balanceResults5">
                                <table class="table table-condensed">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="info">
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="Name">Unit Id</button>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="CommNumber">Comm #</button>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="AccountName">Account</button>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="col-sm-2">
                                                <button name="sortColumn" class="btn btn-link btn-link-header" type="submit" value="ChargeNumber">Charge #</button>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>IASdev1
                                            </td>
                                            <td>16100160</td>
                                            <td>Overhead
                                            </td>
                                            <td>ABC130257109</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>IASdev2
                                            </td>
                                            <td>16258798</td>
                                            <td>Overhead
                                            </td>
                                            <td>130257109</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-light {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    border-color: #080808;
}
.navbar-light-footer {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.navbar-light-page {
    background-color: grey;
}
.navbar-light-text {
    color: antiquewhite;
}
.navbar-header-spacer {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.panel {
  border: none;
}

.panel-heading-collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-heading-collapsible:after {
  margin-right: 10px;

  /* symbol for "opening" panels */
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
  content: "\e114"; /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
  float: right; /* adjust as needed */
  color: grey; /* adjust as needed */
}

.panel-heading-collapsible.collapsed:after {
  /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
  content: "\e080"; /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}

.panel-body {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.panel .panel-section {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .panel .panel-section:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: lightsteelblue #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

.btn-link-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

I, along with a colleague, experimented with several possibilities including using top/left instead of position: absolute; placing each panel in a row div (which "fixed" with width until I added padding or margins to shift the panels back over, but did not fix the height); adjusting the width and height values which did not help on screens of different resolutions; and moving the overlay div to different places in the HTML. Searches for possible reasons why a div would extend beyond its parents all seemed to point to an absence of `box-sizing: border-box;` on one or more of the divs in the HTML. As you can see in the supplied code (and realized on the fiddle page), it did not make a difference.

I know I'm missing something to constrain the overlay properly, but at this point I'm not sure what that something is.

The following stackoverflow pages seemed to come closest to matching my scenario, but did not prove fruitful in resolving the particular issue I'm seeing:

[Div tags extending beyond their own margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710255/div-tags-extending-beyond-their-own-margins)
[CSS: Absolute positioned div extending beyond overflow:hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963708/css-absolute-positioned-div-extending-beyond-overflowhidden)
[Why do child divs extend beyond their parent div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571502/why-do-child-divs-extend-beyond-their-parent-div)
[Div extends beyond wrapper div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330353/div-extends-beyond-wrapper-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give `position:relative;` for `.panel-collapse`

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/phnwqs0w/1/